# center an input element inside a nested div

Tags: html, css

How to center the **input** html element inside the nested **div** element.
The following fiddle was created which tries to center the **input** element using **margin: 0 auto;** property which does not work 
http://jsfiddle.net/mc4sj8rv/1/

```
<div id="login_container">
    <div class="auth-form">
        <div class="auth-input">
            <input id="signup_username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#login_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none scroll 0% 0% #F8F8F8;
}
input[type=password] {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use `text-align: center` to `.auth-input`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#login_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none scroll 0% 0% #F8F8F8;
}
input[type=password] {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.auth-input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="login_container">
  <div class="auth-form">
    <div class="auth-input">
      <input id="signup_username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply text-align:

```
.auth-input{text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 2):

The input element is an inline element so you can't center it with `margin:0 auto;`. You can use `text-align:center;` on a parent :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/mc4sj8rv/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements are centred using `text-align: center` on their parent element (and your selector doesn't match your input anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
text-align: center;
```

to center a div's content horizontally.